# Blender fluid simulation "with drag" (simulating a pump)

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I need to do a fluid simulation, where the fluid goes through a pump. 
The pump-model is build the way, that the intake is at the bottom and the output is at the top. I need a way to get the fluid all the way up through the pump. I believe there's no thing like a "drag water from here to there and also mind the obstacles" option for this, is there? Is there another way?
The only way i can think of is having a tank/reservoir that is as high (or higher) than the pump, so that the water rises up all the way through the pump.

So, basically i need to simulate the pump.

Here's a picture to help explain what i need to achieve:
[image]

Comment: Possibly use a fluid ‘Control’ object moving in the direction yuvwant to drag the fluid, set with a Velocity Force tk transfer its velocity into the fluid - but I’ve never actually trief anything like that before so can’t be sure.

Comment: never tried it with fluid sims but could you not just set the gravity negative?

Comment: No, the fluid needs to behave properly.

Comment: I elaborated on my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you could use a chain of control objects which follow a path in the center of the pipe. I have attached my blender file that generates this animation.

I have a pipe (which would be your pump) set to Obstacle under Fluids and it has Shell initialization.

I have a domain surrounding the simulation and some fluid at the bottom to be sucked up.

The most important thing is the short cylinder which is a Control fluid object. Play with "Attraction" and "Velocity" to get suction. It follows a path I made in the center of the pipe. Perhaps you could use an array of these controls to have a constant suction/drag on the water. Or you could cheat and have an "inflow" at the end of the out pipe and an "outflow" at the opening. Then if your pipe is not transparent, it will look like water is going in and coming out. I can make an example of this if you want.

[image: gif]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try it and tell you the result. I don't want to mark this as answer right now, in case there are other people with suggestions. (I'll do it latter).

Answer (score 2):

Rather than 'draw' the water up the pipe (or have a high reservoir), you could use an Inflow set with a high velocity to force the water up the pipe :

[image: water pipe inflow]

Here the selected object is the Inflow, set with X Velocity of -5 to inject the water at high speed. The fluid that seeps back out of the inflow could easily be blocked with an additional (hidden) obstacle if desired - or hidden via a Boolean modifier.

Blend file included [image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem however is, that the pump internally is not just a pipe. Its more like chambers, roters and stuff.

Comment: @Reaper I'm not really clear on what you're trying to achieve. If you're trying to *simulate* the internals of the pump (rather than just producing an animations showing the operation of the pump) then I don't think Blender is the right tool for the job. Presumably, you'd need moving obstacles that 'push' the water around and the resultant pressure pushes the water through the pump - Blender fluid simulation doesn't work very well with moving obstacles so this is unlikely to work - and less likely to be realistic.

Answer (score 0):

Give inflow where you want the pump to be and add an obstacle below it for the water to go up. The water goes up, falls down to the tank. Then flows in to the pipe and disappears hitting the outflow that's the rim of the tank.